# Key Error while Parsing Json file using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

We have Source as Json File and we are trying to parse the data and create an output CSV file

In some cases , we don't receive some of the attributes which in the Json file.

When i am trying with the below code to get the length and its values , i am getting "Key Error". Below is my code.

```
for j in range(len(json_file['entity'][i]['data']['attrb']['DEPT']['group'])):
    for key in json_file['entity'][i]['data']['attrb']['DEPT']['group'][j].keys():
        try:
            temp[key] = json_file['entity'][i]['data']['attrb']['DEPT']['group'][j][key]['values'][0]['value']
        except:
            temp[key] = None
```

`['entity'][i]['data']['attrb']` will always be available but `'DEPT'` for some the `json` files I may not be having it.

**Error:**

> "Key Error: 'DEPT'  not found ".

How can i overcome this issue please help me with any sugggestion..

Please find below sample data..

```
{
  "entity": [
    {
  "data": {
    "attrb": {

      "DEPT": {
        "group": [
          {
            "DEPTID": {
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "D12345"
                }
              ]
            },
            "DEPTNO": {
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "302222201"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 ]

 }
```

Comment: To help you, we'll also need to see the JSON data.

Comment: As an aside, you're iterating over that `['group']` dictionary in a very non-Pythonic way. Look into `.items()` instead of `range()` and `.keys()`.

Comment: @AKX ... Thanks a lot for the reply. I will be adding Sample file in few minutes.

Comment: use `dict.get()` method instead of [] i.e. `json_file.get('entity', [])` instead of `json_file['entity']`

Comment: for dictionaries with uncertain keys. use dict.get(key, default) instead. Which will return default value if key is not there

Comment: @SagunShrestha .. Can i specify complete mapping inside the .get() function ? I mean complete mapping "    json_file['entity'][i]['data']['attrb']['DEPT']['group']  "

Comment: @BlueRineS .. Please help me with some syntax if you have any , i am just started with python few days back..

Comment: @AKX .. Added Sample data for one of the file. For some of the files i will get the attribute 'DEPT' for some of the files i will not be getting 'DEPT' for those files i am getting this issue. please suggest

Comment: @Ravi `json_file.get('entity', [{}]*n)[i].get('data', {}).get('attrib', {}).get('DEPT', {}).get('group', '')` where n is the possible max length of that list. If you only keep `[{}]`, you may get an IndexError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down step by step.

your string is

```
import json   

json_string = '''{
  "entity": [
    {
  "data": {
    "attrb": {
      "DEPT": {
        "group": [
          {
            "DEPTID": {
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "D12345"
                }
              ]
            },
            "DEPTNO": {
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "302222201"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
 }'''
```

and the resulting json dictionary:

```
test = json.loads(json_string)
```

First, return all the attributes (you metion 'attrib' is assumed to be a valid key).

```
attribs = [test['entity'][i]['data']['attrb'] for i in range(len(test['entity']))]
```

Now the attribs outputs something as

```
>>> attribs
[{'DEPT': {'group': [{'DEPTID': {'values': [{'value': 'D12345'}]},
 'DEPTNO': {'values': [{'value': '302222201'}]}}]}}]
```

Subsequently, as you mention, 'DEPT' may or may not be a valid key. From this point on we use de dict.get method:

```
dept = attribs[0].get('DEPT')
>>> dept
{'group': [{'DEPTID': {'values': [{'value': 'D12345'}]},
'DEPTNO': {'values': [{'value': '302222201'}]}}]}
```

if however, 'DEPT' would be no valid key, then get('DEPT') will return None:

```
_dict= {}
>>> print(_dict.get('DEPT'))
None
```

Alternatively, is you wish to return some other default value other than None, then you would

```
_dict.get('DEPT', your_default_value)
```

where your_default_value is an arbitrary variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can i share my complete code with you .. ?

Comment: sure. But did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: Not exactly solved , want to know where did i missed. Can i mail the code to you or do i need to paste it here ?

Comment: paste it in hyperlink.

Comment: I added the code in form of hyperlink..Thats my existing code. Please please have a look and help me with some suggestion..

Comment: this should [work](https://tio.run/##rVLBaoQwEL3nK4KXGCiyu7YXoTd76KXtoTcJxa2pTXUT0VhYxG@3M8lW3F0vhQYSZl7em0zy0hztp9HxNKlDY1pLvzqjCS5vnW2VLuk9ZYwNhNJAaqvsMUhoBhmlDitymwMyOCTIrW33LnU5IOnDy@u875CyNX0zF/FjWMQn0WN6JjvtfOd1L7sL9VqNJR/oQbrdxbd3wRVnvEDEWT7eXDf29PyvjcWbHY7N9s@9kbX4l@MRt@ICU4AnI1hJvLuFerfgLcZRbfKiCxemc89BO9W@A1o2azLmvwETmRIZQ/8hZM55JuiHaamiStM216UMa6nDFSnnglh5aKDyMBLU@KNQuDw5cbeo8A/i0zOXwtMB4BlRKW1YcYdjwahvoCMZDlWCvJET0sCFbIibfJp@AA)